# Argument type string | ArrayBuffer is not assignable to parameter type string

Tags: typescript, filereader

Getting a TS error in line 15 particularly in `e.target.result`.

> Argument type string | ArrayBuffer is not assignable to parameter type string  Type ArrayBuffer is not assignable to type string

```
let fileTag = document.getElementById("filetag"),
    preview = document.getElementById("preview");

fileTag.addEventListener("change", function() {
    changeImage(this);
});

function changeImage(input) {
    let reader;

    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
        reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function(e) {
            preview.setAttribute('src', e.target.result);
        }

        reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
}
```

added HTML

```html
<div class="img-container">
<input type="file" id="filetag">
<img src="" class="profImage" id="preview" alt="profilePic">
</div>
```

Comment: Typescript type system is not powerful enough to express this kind of typing, therefore you'll have to cast `e.target.result as string`.

Comment: In JavaScript everything works perfectly as you can see it here - https://jsfiddle.net/s7e1uhx4/

Comment: @georg can you give me an example with some more code?

Comment: @cypho my editor gives me the error and when i run it on localhost the image doesn't show up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Independently of the actual answer, consider [using `URL.createObjectURL`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File_API/Using_files_from_web_applications#example_using_object_urls_to_display_images) instead of converting the `File` to a `data:` URI; it will save you some resources on spurious string conversions.)

---

The problem is that type checking works locally.

```
let preview = document.getElementById("preview");
let reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function(e) {
    preview.setAttribute('src', e.target.result);
}
```

Based on surrounding context, TypeScript knows that `preview` is a DOM node, and therefore `preview.setAttribute` expects two string arguments. It also knows that `e.target` is a [`FileReader`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader), and therefore [its property `result`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/result) may be either a string or an `ArrayBuffer`. Which one it is depends on the method that was earlier called on the `FileReader`, but this information is hard to express in a type system and is not available within the event handler anyway. For all the type checker knows, the event handler may have been invoked after `readAsArrayBuffer` was called somewhere far, far away on the same `FileReader` object.

Since in this case you know better than the type checker, you can use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to convince it that the value is indeed a string:

```
reader.onload = function(e) {
    preview.setAttribute('src', e.target.result as string);
}
```

If you don’t want to litter your code with type assertions everywhere, consider wrapping your code in an abstraction that is easier to type check, for example like this:

```
function readFileAsDataURL(file): Promise<string> {
    return new Promise((accept, reject) => {
        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (ev) {
            accept(ev.target.result as string);
        };
        /* XXX: rejecting with an event is rather unorthodox */
        reader.onabort = reader.onerror = function (ev) {
            reject(ev);
        }
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    });
}

async function changeImage(input) {
    preview.setAttribute('src', await readFileAsDataURL(input.files[0]));
}
```

Now if you remember to use `readFileAsDataURL` everywhere in your code instead of constructing `FileReader`s directly, the only place where a type assertion will be required is inside that one function.

Answer (score -1):

You might be able to do:

```
function ab2str(buf: ArrayBuffer): string {
    return String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint16Array(buf));
}
// ...
reader.readAsDataURL(typeof input.files[0] === 'string' ? input.files[0] : ab2str(input.files[0]))
```

Or, if you are positive it will always be a string:

```
reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0] as string);
```

basically if it's a string, just use it, but if it's an ArrayBuffer, first convert it to a string.  Not sure if typescript will be able to follow that though.

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/06/How-to-convert-ArrayBuffer-to-and-from-String

Otherwise, just do:

```
preview.setAttribute('src', e.target.result as string);
```

again, assuming you are positive it will actually always be a string